# Spam safe email address

Tags: support

If I add my email address to my profile (in particular, in the "About Me" box) such that it is in the proper format (name@domain.tld) will it be vulnerable to harvesting by spam bots?

It would be nice if for example only logged in users with a sufficiently high reputation could see it as a clickable link and others as something that is human but not (or much harder) machine readable.

Answer (score 5):

The email field is only visible to yourself and moderators.

Comment: Yes, but I mean if I put it in the "About Me" box. I know that nobody else except the moderators can see it, that is why I put it in that box.

Comment: @Jonas I don't know how effective this is against spam-bots, but I've seen some people spell their emails out in the format of "name [at] domain.com"

Comment: @Jin http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work - here's some discussion about how effective various types of email address obfuscation is.

Comment: Does "entity obfuscation" work? On my (rather publicly viewable department homepage), I list my e-mail address by replacing the username and the @ symbol with HTML entities, i.e. `&#x0077;&#x0077;278<span>&#x0040;</span>dpmms...` and it has worked well enough for the past years. But I assume SE has some sort of HTML sanitation on user input fields, so I wonder if this will work?

Comment: @Raeder: Thanks for the link. Seeing the second answer at the page you have linked I suppose I'll just put the email address in the correct format.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen, sorry, I misunderstood.